# Activity Result APIs is not returning callback for RequestPermission Contract

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I am not getting permission result callback on Activity Result api as mentioned in the doc.

[Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin)

I am using `implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha02"`

**Here is the api code :**

```
/**
 * An {@link ActivityResultContract} to {@link Activity#requestPermissions request a permission}
 */
public static class RequestPermission extends ActivityResultContract<String, Boolean> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Intent createIntent(@NonNull String input) {
        return new Intent(ACTION_REQUEST_PERMISSIONS)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSIONS, new String[] { input });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Boolean parseResult(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return false;
        if (intent == null) return false;
        int[] grantResults = intent.getIntArrayExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANT_RESULTS);
        if (grantResults == null) return false;
        return grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

**Here is my implementation :**

```
private val permission = prepareCall(object : ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission() {
    override fun createIntent(input: String): Intent {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(input)) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale - true",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            // case 2
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale - false",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            // case 1 and 3
        }
        return super.createIntent(input)
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        val t = super.parseResult(resultCode, intent)
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "parseResult $t", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return t
    }
}) {
    Log.d("permission granted?", "$it")
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        permission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
}
```

As per doc, I should be getting callback inside `ActivityResultCallback` but after backtracking I figure in my case, it even does not call `ParseResult` function. Though I am still receiving callback inside `onRequestPermissionsResult` function.

So, am I doing something wrong ?

Please refer [Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin) to understand this api.

**Update**

I was able to get the callback after extending my activity with `ComponentActivity` but again, if the permission is already given then app wont receive callback, is there any way to directly handle here? I don't wanna check self permission.

Sample demo code - https://github.com/tasneembohra/ActivityResultApiDemo

Comment: This is old post, it is working as expected in stable api

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation, hope it helps:

```
      val cameraPermission = prepareCall(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){
            if(it){
                Log.e("TAG", "permnission granted")
            }else{
                Log.e("TAG", "No permnission")
            }
        }

        cameraPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
```

It enters Permission Granted condition, if you granted permission earlier and just open app, or grant it now.

P.S. My Activity extends **AppCompatActivity**

Answer (score 0):

Well I ran in a lot of circles trying to solve the same problem, but my solution was to simply remove the override `onActivityResult` from my activity!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily handle your permissions callback by creating a support class extending `DefaultLifecycleObserver`

```kotlin
class PermissionHandler(
    private val context: Context,
    private val registry: ActivityResultRegistry
    ) : DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private val permissionsKey = "permissionsKey"

    private lateinit var requestPermissions: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>

    private var onAllowed: (() -> Unit)? = null
    private var onDenied: (() -> Unit)? = null

    private val readExternalStorageRequest = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    )

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        requestPermissions = registry.register(permissionsKey, owner, ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { result ->

            Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "RESULT: $result")

            if (result.values.isNullOrEmpty() || result.values.contains(false)) {
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "DENIED")
                onDenied?.invoke()
            }
            else {
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "ALLOWED")
                onAllowed?.invoke()
            }
        }
    }

    fun checkForPermissions(permissions: Array<String> = readExternalStorageRequest, onAllowed: (() -> Unit)?, onDenied: (() -> Unit)?) {
        this.onAllowed = onAllowed
        this.onDenied = onDenied

        val remainingPermissions = mutableListOf<String>()
        remainingPermissions.clear()

        for (permission in permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                remainingPermissions.add(permission)
            }
        }

        Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "REMAINING: $remainingPermissions")

        if (remainingPermissions.isNotEmpty()) {
            requestPermissions.launch(remainingPermissions.toTypedArray())
        }
        else {
            onAllowed?.invoke()
        }
    }

}
```

###### then use it in your `activity` or `fragment`

```kotlin
    private lateinit var permissionHandler: PermissionHandler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
        permissionHandler = PermissionHandler(this, activityResultRegistry)
        lifecycle.addObserver(permissionHandler)
    }

    fun foo() {
        permissionHandler.checkForPermissions(
                onAllowed = {
                    //on allowed stuffs...
                },
                onDenied = {
                    //on denied stuffs...
                }
            )
    }
```

###### for `fragment`

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        permissionHandler = PermissionHandler(requireContext(), requireActivity().activityResultRegistry)
        lifecycle.addObserver(permissionHandler)
    }
```